# vue use elementUI <el-popover> in table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I've a button that opens a `Popover` element. In the dialog I've two buttons: `Cancel` and `Sure`, when I click on one of these I want to close the dialog.
How can I do that?

This is my code:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:function(){
    return {
      data:[
      {
        id:1,
        name: 'jak',
        age: 24
      },
      {
        id:2,
        name: 'irol',
        age: 34
      }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    edit(){},
    remove(){
      // how can i cancel the el-popover
    },
    otherClick(){
    
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.5.17-beta.0/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/element-ui/2.3.2/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <el-table :data="data" style="width:100%" border>
      <el-table-column prop="id" label="id" ></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name" ></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="age" label="Age" ></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column label="Action">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          <el-button type="primary" class="mr-20" @click="edit(scope)">Edit</el-button>
          
          <el-popover placement="top" trigger="click" title="Sure？">
            <div class="btn-confirm">
              <el-button type="text" size="mini" @click="otherClick">Cancel</el-button>
              <el-button type="primary" size="mini" @click="remove(scope)">Sure</el-button>
            </div>
            <el-button type="danger" slot="reference">Delete</el-button>
          </el-popover>
        </template>


      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
</div>
```

Comment: "unclear what you're asking" Please clarify your specific problem ?

Comment: when I click the Delete Button , I click the Cancel Button or Sure Button , how to hidden the el-popover

Comment: "unclear what you're asking" Please clarify your specific problem ?

Comment: This seems to me like a bug in `<el-popover>`, it should properly check the `defaultPrevented` property

Comment: see the code snippet

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to **define a property to show/hide the dialog** in the `data` attribute:

   data:[
   {
   id:1,
   name: 'jak',
   age: 24,
   showDialog: false
   },
2. Then **add the v-`model` property** to the `el-popover`:
3. And finally **define the action on `Cancel/Sure` button**, for the 'Cancel' you could simply set the property to `false`:

   <el-button type="text" size="mini" @click="scope.row.showDialog=false">Cancel

For the 'Sure', since you have to add more code, you can set the property in the click method:

```
remove(row){
  //DO THE REMOVE ACTION!
  row.showDialog=false;
}
```

Please take a look to the complete example:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:function(){
    return {
      data:[
      {
        id:1,
        name: 'jak',
        age: 24,
        showDialog: false
      },
      {
        id:2,
        name: 'irol',
        age: 34,
        showDialog: false
      }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    edit(){},
    remove(row){
      //DO THE REMOVE ACTION!
      row.showDialog = false;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.4.7/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<template>
  <el-table :data="data" style="width:100%" border>
      <el-table-column prop="id" label="id" ></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name" ></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="age" label="Age" ></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column label="Action">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          <el-button type="primary" @click="edit(scope)">Edit</el-button><br/>
          <el-button type="danger" slot="reference" @click="scope.row.showDialog=true">Delete</el-button>
          
          <el-popover trigger="click" title="Sure？" v-model="scope.row.showDialog">
            <div class="btn-confirm">
              <el-button type="text" size="mini" @click="scope.row.showDialog=false">Cancel</el-button>
              <el-button type="primary" size="mini" @click="remove(scope.row)">Sure</el-button>
            </div>
          </el-popover>
        </template>


      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
</template>
</div>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: I think it's not working example. Because when you click on any delete button all popovers will be opened. For fix this you need to add showDialogs variable, where you will put information about every popover status(open/closed) and set v-model="showDialogs[scope.row.id]".

Comment: Thanks @ГеннадийПрохоренко I fixed it and I also make the snippet executable, 3 years later :-). Bye.

Answer (score 0):

This dose not work if you have more than 2 records, e.g., using below data:

```
data:[
  {
    id:1,
    name: 'jak',
    age: 24
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name: 'irol',
    age: 34
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name: 'irol1',
    age: 34
  }
  {
    id:4,
    name: 'irol2',
    age: 35
  },
  ]
```

3 delete confirm dialog will show at the same time.

Comment: A good work workaround I found is here: https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000010256899

Answer (score 0):

several hours later and a little of code diggin I finally found the way.
Use ':ref'

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.5.17-beta.0/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/element-ui/2.3.2/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <el-table :data="data" style="width:100%" border>
      <el-table-column prop="id" label="id" ></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name" ></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="age" label="Age" ></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column label="Action">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          <el-button type="primary" @click="edit(scope)">Edit</el-button><br/>
          <el-button type="danger" slot="reference" @click="showDialog=true">Delete</el-button>

          <el-popover trigger="click" :ref="'popover'+scope.$index">
            <div class="btn-confirm">
              <el-button type="text" size="mini" @click="remove(scope.$index)">Cancel</el-button>
              <el-button type="primary" size="mini" @click="remove(scope)">Sure</el-button>
            </div>
          </el-popover>
        </template>


  </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:function(){
    return {
      showDialog: false,
      data:[
      {
        id:1,
        name: 'jak',
        age: 24
      },
      {
        id:2,
        name: 'irol',
        age: 34
      }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    edit(){},
    remove(popRef){
      //DO THE REMOVE ACTION!
      var child = this.$refs[popRef].doClose();
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<el-table :data="rows">
<el-table-column prop="name" label="Name" ></el-table-column>
<el-table-column fixed="right" label="Operations">
  <template slot-scope="scope">
    <el-popover placement="right" trigger="click">
      <ul class="table-popover-list">
        <li>Copy</li>
        <li>Edit</li>
        <li>Remove</li>
      </ul>
      <el-button size="mini" slot="reference">...</el-button>
    </el-popover>
  </template>
</el-table-column>
```

Comment: Please provide a description for your answer.